# Is there a way to insert text Value into a image column and retrieve it back

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to insert a String value into a image column in a table. Tried converting into VARBINARY(MAX) and inserting into image column. Stored as Null. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Show your code that does the inserting and retrieving. And no one should be using the image datatype at this late date - it has been deprecated for almost 20 years.

Comment: Why would you want to store a string is an `image` column in the first place? As for what's happening, show us what you're trying here. Give us an [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
create table Foo( Bar Image );
insert into Foo ( Bar ) values ( Cast( N'Hello.' as VarBinary(64) ) );
select Bar,
  Cast( Cast( Bar as VarBinary(64) ) as NVarChar(32) ) As RecoveredString
  from Foo;
```

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b17baf13807d9b26243f35a43aba9167).

Helpful reading: [Data type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

---

Extreme handholding update:

```
create table Foo( Bar Image );
declare @String as VarChar(max) = '<HTML>I can''t be bothered to make an attempt.<\HTML>';
insert into Foo ( Bar ) values ( Cast( @String as VarBinary(max) ) );
select Bar,
  Cast( Cast( Bar as VarBinary(max) ) as VarChar(max) ) As RecoveredString
  from Foo;
```

New [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a8237300e61116466a56ee64afba9978).

Comment: Declare @String VARCHAR(max) = '<HTML CODE>'